# How to get/retrieve corrupt/error .java file

Tags: ubuntu, file-recovery

Due to my system power off my .java file looks like below.

```
\B5\F3|F03{9....
```

file size is 50KB so i am hoping it still have data by something went wrong.

In netbeans it shows error

```
Invalid byte 1 of 1-Byte UTF-8 sequence
```

Something is messed by, i don't have any backup and there is no History in netbeans.

Can someone guide me with some ideas to get the code from the above file.

Comment: Was the source file anywhere near 50KB before this corruption? What OS are you on?

Comment: Not sure, i never saw the file size, (a similar kind of project has 10KB file), i am using ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Comment: Might see if anything shows in a utility like TestDisk, http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_ext2 , note that you want to output to a different partition. or PhotoRec for ext3/ext4 http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: could you try to open that file using maybe ms word or open office and see what is the result?

Comment: Opening in Libre Office shows
    ���3{9#APIb��J#���J1O#ilv)

Answer (score 0):

Well, because it seems the file content's has been overwritten then there is nothing much you can do except try to recover it.

I guess you could try to recover the file using third party data recovery software such as [recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) or from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software) list